# WPF Datagrid hell

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'm trying to replace the default method of inserting/deleting/editing items in a datagrid by introducing buttons for Add/Edit/Delete. Should be simple enough, right?
I've tried to do this right by using MVVM and I have the following commands implemented, each bound to the buttons respectively:

- Add - adds a new object to the underlying ObservableCollection
- Delete - deletes the selected item (also databound) from the collection.
- Edit - this one was tricky, following a advice from a different question I used an attached dependency property on the datagrid to invoke it's BeginEdit().

Coming from WinForms, I found this an "interesting" way of doing things, but hey, I'm just getting with the program. Oh, I forgot to mention I'm also doing validation with IDataErrorInfo and I have "ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True" on the column binding. Validation is simply checking for non-empty value.

Here's my problem:

1. User clicks Add, new row is added but it's invalid (since value is blank).
2. User selects newly added row, then clicks Edit.
3. User decides to cancel that by hitting ESC **once**. Cell remains invalid.
4. User now selects a different (valid) row, hits Edit. The cell in the currently selected row doesn't go into edit mode, and BeginEdit() returns false.
5. Stubborn user decides to delete the newly added row (which is still invalid), everything now "looks valid". User once again attempts to edit a different row, but BeginEdit() still returns false.

It seems that even though the row was deleted, the DataGrid is stuck in "invalid" mode. I've tried calling CancelEdit() but that doesn't fix it.

Any help on accomplishing what was supposed to be a **really** simple task (back in the good old' winform days) would be greatly appreciated! :)
Oh, and if I'm doing things completely wrong, or even using the wrong control, please feel free to scold me :)

Comment: You're doing everything totally wrong. Otherwise you wouldn't have any problems since WPF is perfect and doesn't have any flaws. </sarcasm>. No one can tell you what is wrong until you post some sample code that exhibits the exact problem.

Comment: Try to build it idiot proof and someone builds a better idiot (end-users)...  The wonderful world we live in...

Comment: We found a solution, though it seems strange that I'd have to do this since the grid is bound to an obseravable collection - the solution is to call Datagrid.Items.Refresh after deleting an item from the collection.